# Java pass formatted Calendar object to method

Tags: java, calendar, format

I want to pass a formatted timestamp to a method using Calendar (using Java 1.6.0_22). I have a method with this signature:

```
public void setTimestamp(Calendar param0);
```

To get the timestamp, I did this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), 
        cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

I want it formatted in this way:

```
yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

Then pass it to the method. I can't change the method as I didn't make it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just `new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").format(calendar.getTime())`?

Comment: I tried passing it like that but the method wouldn't take it. Compiler error.

Comment: What's the error? Missing 'import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;'? BTW, The format should change to `yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: It tells me to change the method to take a String instead of Calendar. I can't change the method signature.

Comment: Does `public void setTimestamp(Calendar param0)` belong to a class without source code? And your program want to call it with a formated string `yyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`?

Comment: There is source code. But I'm not allowed to change it. Company uses it for other programs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114290/discussion-between-beckyang-and-m-o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is convert the string to `Date` first, then set it to `Calendar`.

```
    String input = "2016-05-11T14:44:09";
    java.util.Date date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(input);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    obj.setTimestamp(cal);
```